# Spree VAT included prices with promo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

We have Spree application, version 3.0.0. Item prices are in GBP and EUR, and include 20% VAT. I have created promo, with 25% discount on specific taxon.

When code is applied on item, updated total calculated incorrectly:

> Price with VAT - discount - total

We want:

> Price before VAT - discount - VAT - total

I've checked the docs and github and found this issue and PR https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/6475

What I noticed, that everything works correctly once I add another item to cart.

Not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

That, after adding the code, Order total was calculated as the `Price before VAT - discount (promotions) - VAT - Order total`, it is necessary to set the **Action** for **Promotion** in the **Create per-line-item adjustment** and setting the **Calculator** for it in **Percent Per Item**.
[image]